# Excel VBA macro to copy certain columns to another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy certain columns of one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet.

In order to do so, I have a macro:

```
    Sub Submit()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = 
     Workbooks("Submission_Form.xlsm").Worksheets("RGSheet").Columns("A")
    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("I:\Projects\...\Macros\RG.csv")
    Worksheets(1).Select
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("RG.csv").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
    End Sub
```

However, when the cursor hits targetColumn, it gives error:

```
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have put RG.csv in the same folder as Submission_Form.xlsm. So I am really confused why is it giving error.

I would also like to know how to handle if the RG.csv is located in another directory.

Comment: It's a csv file? Is it open in excel when you try to set `targetColumn` or is it just a csv file in that folder? If it's not open you'll have to open it first, then set your Target column.

Comment: A csv can only have 1 "worksheet" - does it do the same thing if you index it directly?  `Workbooks("RG.csv").Worksheets(1)`

Comment: Worked fine using index too. another question- How can I select data from sourceColumn A4 onwards till there is data.  targetColumn functionality stays the same

Comment: updated post with working code so far

Comment: @SilverFish I can't reproduce your issue - Are you sure you've got the right workbook and worksheet names?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because Submission_Form.xlsm isn't opened(?). Your code looks a little inconsistent.  Maybe just open both source and destination, and copy the column. Something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Submit()
    Dim vSourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim vDestinationWorkbook As Workbook

    Set vSourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("Submission_Form.xlsm")
    Set vDestinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("I:\Projects\...\Macros\RG.csv")

    vSourceWorkbook.Worksheets("RGSheet").Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=vDestinationWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
End Sub
```